# How to monitor status of vips on cisco 11501 through SNMP

Tags: cisco, load-balancing, snmp

I'd like to use SNMP to monitor the servers that are in rotation on my cisco 11501 load balancer.

I'm having trouble finding the OIDs I need to achieve this task though.  I've tried using the OIDs documented in [Management Information Base (MIB) Overview](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/app_ntwk_services/data_center_app_services/css11500series/v8.10/configuration/administration/guide/SNMP.html#wp1015592), specifically cntsvcExt.mib
(OID 1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.368.1.18).  However, it seems I need to pass in a more specific OID to get the info I need out.

Does anyone know of any docs or tools I can use to find out how to get this info and interpret it?

Comment: What SNMP information are you trying to get?  In the absence of anything better, you could see if an snmpwalk returned anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

I've not used an 11501 but in my previous experience with other cisco load balancers the best steps are to:

- get mib2.tar.gz from ftp.cisco.com
- extract this in your mibs dir for your snmp client (probably something like /usr/share/snmp/mibs/...
- walk the entire device using snmpwalk into a file
- look in the file for one of the VIP IPs or backend server IPs

You'll probably see the giant section of all stats available for the VIP around there.  Then you can take the oids that will be in that file and put them in your monitoring software.